# How to use Find statement with 'If/else statement' using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use `find` command with `if..else` statement. What I actually want to do is, search for a specific string in multiple log files. If I find that string I want to append the name of that file with "Passed" else "Failed" into another text file.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
if (find /n /i "0 error" "filename.log") (
    echo "Passed" > log.txt
) else (
    echo "Failed" > log.txt
)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to do this in the normal command line or through Powershell? You have tagged as both, but your comment says using CMD.

Comment: sorry, edited it. I want to use CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

To get a `.txt` file containing only the names of the logs in the current directory which contained `0 error`:

```bat
FindStr /MIC:"0 Error" *.log>"Passed.txt"
```

If you wanted a `log.txt` to prodvide feedback on each log file in the current directory, instead…

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
(For %A In (*.log) Do @FindStr /MIC:"0 Error" "%A">Nul&&(@Echo %A Passed)||@Echo %A Failed)>"log.txt"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
(For %%A In (*.log) Do FindStr /MIC:"0 Error" "%%A">Nul&&(
    Echo %%A Passed)||Echo %%A Failed)>"log.txt"
```

Comment: This was totally what I wanted, Thanks for the solution, just one thing. It is writing the whole content in log.txt file eg if it found the string then the result in log .txt is :  C:\CODEDUI_TestAutomation\Models\MSBuildData\MSBuldLog>FindStr /MIC:"0 Error" "LocalMSBuild_Build_bd_CLR_Cmd and SettingFile1.log" 1>Nul  && (Echo LocalMSBuild_Build_bd_CLR_Cmd and SettingFile1.log Passed )  || Echo LocalMSBuild_Build_bd_CLR_Cmd and SettingFile1.log Failed 
LocalMSBuild_Build_bd_CLR_Cmd and SettingFile1.log Passed

Comment: Can It have just the last line written in the file?

Comment: @AnujMittal, when I said `existing batch file`, I assumed you already had `@Echo Off` at some line above it, _as I did in your provided code_! I've updated my example.

Answer (score 2):

CMD/batch doesn't support commands in `if` statements. You need to evaluate the errorlevel (the exit code of the command) after running the command:

```
set "logfile=filename.log"
find /n /i "0 error" "%logfile%" >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    >>log.txt echo %logfile% - Passed
) else (
    >>log.txt echo %logfile% - Failed
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working in case of fail , and I will be using this  for multiple files, so can this be modified more. Also, it doesn't append the name of file with that. I need to run a batch file for multiple files at once that can do this task.

Comment: @AnujMittal "it is not working" is not a problem description. What behavior do you observe? What behavior do you expect? What filename do you want to append, and where?

Comment: It says "Passed" even after the string "0 error" was not present. In the log.txt file created It only says "Passed", what i need to have is "Filename - Passed". In case of my multiple files scenario, I want if that exact string is present is should say passed else failed for eg: the sring is "0 Error" so the output should be in a log.txt file with "Filename1 - Passes Filename2- Passed Filename3- Failed" and so on till all the files in a folder are read.

Comment: then just store the file name in a variable and print the variable instead

Comment: I am very new to working with cmd, can you please give an example how to do it.

Comment: @AnujMittal *It says "Passed" even after the string "0 error" was not present.* No, it doesn't. Not unless you modified the code from my answer, or the file *does* contain the string "0 error" despite your claims otherwise.